# Show that if $\ker(T^j) = \ker(T^{j+1})$ then $V= \ker(T^j) + \operatorname{Im}(T^j)$ is a direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I´m trying to prove this: If $V$ is a vectorial space (with finite dimension) and $T:V\to V$ a linear transformation. Assume there is a $j$ (a natural number)  for which it is true: $\ker(T^j)$ = $\ker(T^{j+1})$ and $\operatorname{Im}(T^j)$ = $\operatorname{Im}(T^{j+1})$. Prove that $ V = \ker T^j + \operatorname{Im} T^j$ is a direct sum.

---

This is what I tried to do. First: I used the rank-nullity Theorem:
$\dim(\ker T^j) + \dim(\operatorname{Im}(T^j)) = \dim(V)$
So now, I have 2 ways to prove that it is a direct sum: The first one is related with the intersection of the two subspaces and the other one is about trying to prove that for each $v$ that belongs to $V$ there is an $x$ that belongs to $\ker(T^j)$ and $y$ that belongs to $\operatorname{Im}(T^j)$ and then $v = x + y$.

---

First I tried to follow the idea from a similar example that I saw where j=2 (but it didn´t work). Assume v belongs to V, then $$ T^j (v) = T^{j+1} (v)  $$ (Is that correct?)  $So, T^j(v) - T^{j+1}(v) = 0$
Then, $T^j(v- T(v)) = 0.$ So $v-T(v)=x$ belongs to the kernel of $T^j.$ And I can write $v = T(v) + x$. but the problem here is that it´s not useful,I want v equal to $x + T^j(v)$ for example so I can conclude that is a direct sum. I´d appreciate some help

Comment: The equality $T^jv=T^{j+1}v$ for all $v$ is not correct. The conclusion can be proved as follows. If $\ker(T^j)\cap {\rm Im}\,(T^j)\neq 0,$ then there is $v$ such that $T^jv\neq 0$ and $T^{2j}v=0,$ i.e.$v\in \ker(T^{2j})=\ker(T^j).$ Hence $T^jv=0,$ which gives a contradiction.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: That looks more like an answer than a comment to me.

Comment: @joriki OK. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality $T^jv=T^{j+1}v$ for all $v$ is not correct. The conclusion can be proved as follows. The assumption $\ker T^j=\ker T^{j+1}$ implies $\ker T^j=\ker T^{i}$ for $i>j.$ If $\ker T^j\cap {\rm Im}\,T^j\neq 0$ then there is $v$ such that $T^jv\neq 0$ and $T^{2j}v=0,$ i.e.$v\in \ker T^{2j}=\ker T^j. $ Hence $T^jv=0,$ which gives a contradiction. As $\dim V=\dim \ker T^j+\dim{\rm Im}\,T^j$ we obtain the conclusion $$ V=\ker T^j\oplus {\rm Im}\,T^j$$